# how to run simultaneous animations at different speeds javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, simultaneous

This code does the job now. The animations are all within the function calls .

function animate() {

```
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        var object = objects[i];

        if (--object.countdown <= 0) {

            object.countdown = object.delay;
        if(i==0){
            advanceTheFleet();
            if(dropLine){
                object.delay-=20;
                if(object.delay<=10){
                    object.delay=10;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            propelMissiles();
        }

    }
}
```

}
animate();

Answer (score 2):

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/4vV5X/

Start with one requestAnimationFrame (because it's efficient at animation loops).

I'm assuming you have created objects for your ship and missle.

Add a `delay` and `countdown` element to each object

```
objects.push({id:"ship",x:20,y:20,vx:1,vy:0,delay:20,countdown:20,color:"green"});

objects.push({id:"missle",x:220,y:20,vx:-1,vy:0,delay:3,countdown:3,color:"red"});
```

Then in requestAnimationFrame you can reduce the countdown for each object.

If the countdown reaches zero you draw that object.

```
for(var i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
    var object=objects[i];

    // if this object's countdown has expired, move it
    if(--object.countdown<=0){

        // reset the countdown

        object.countdown=object.delay;

        // move the object

        object.x+=object.vx;
        object.y+=object.vy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow - a fantastic answer - hope I can use this method. I have set up instances of the ships as array elements - 1=ship exists, 0=no ship (blown up!). Ships are then drawn by referencing the arrays and incrementing the x/y canvas points.  Missiles will be fired by player (keypress or mouseclick) so missile animation start/finish is random. Not sure how I can incorporate this method......